# Jenkins groovy script parameter get from another job

Tags: jenkins, svn, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have one pipeline and one other job. i want to pass parameter.

This is my groovy script which is inside pipeline job.

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage('release') {
            steps {
                echo 'This is release!' 
                echo branch
                build job: projectname , parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'branch', value: branch]]
    }
}
```

So this branch i want to pass into build job. echo branch also printing perfectly.

And this is how i tried to get my branch name from release job

[image]
This trigger an error.

```
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E160005: Target path '/${branch}' does not exist
```

It does not resolve to the branch name which i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
build job: projectname , parameters: [string(name: 'branch', value: "${branch}")]
```